# Remove continuous legend from plotly

Tags: r, r-plotly

I have a basic scatterplot that I've made in plotly (in R). I'm using a continuous input to color the data points which plotly converts into a gradient. However, the `removelegend` option doesn't remove a continuous legend the way it removes a discrete legend.  Consider the example below.

```
data = mtcars
data$vs = as.character(data$vs)

plotly::plot_ly(
  data = data,
  x = ~disp,
  y = ~mpg,
  color = ~vs,
  mode = "markers",
  type = "scatter"
) %>% 
  layout(showlegend = FALSE)
```

[image: First Example Image, No Legend]

```
plotly::plot_ly(
  data = data,
  x = ~disp,
  y = ~mpg,
  color = ~hp,
  mode = "markers",
  type = "scatter"
) %>% 
  layout(showlegend = FALSE)
```

[image: Second Example Image, Legend Present]

Is there a way to remove the continuous legend?

Answer (score 5):

The issue arises because in the continuous case plotly doesn't call it a legend, it's a color bar. The easiest way to remove it is to pipe in `hide_colorbar()`

```
plotly::plot_ly(
  data = data,
  x = ~disp,
  y = ~mpg,
  color = ~hp,
  mode = "markers",
  type = "scatter"
) %>% 
  hide_colorbar()
```